# Azure Application Insights with Java Agent: auto-collected remote dependencies custom properties

Tags: java, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to convert my application from using AI SDK to Application Insights Java Agent, and it seems that custom `TelemetryInitializers` doesn't work with this configuration. Span processors would be enough for my use cases, but I struggle to find a way to populate auto-collected remote dependencies telemetry with custom properties. How should I do it with Java Agent? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#send-custom-telemetry-from-your-application) help you?

Comment: No, this doc shows solutions for auto-collected incoming telemetry (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#dependencies) , and custom outgoing telemetry (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#dependencies), I need to modify auto-collected outgoing telemetry (remote dependencies)